# Necesito insertar un video con javafx en mi proyecto y me da este error

Tags: java, linux, javafx, mediaplayer

Este es mi resultado cuando compilo. Estoy creando un video de la forma mas basica posible y me da error, en otro jdk como por ejemplo 1.8.0_261 si funciona pero el tema esta que no puedo actualizar mi jdk necesito dejarlo tal cual como esta.

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$1(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: MediaException: UNKNOWN : com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player! : com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player!
    at javafx.scene.media.MediaException.exceptionToMediaException(MediaException.java:146)
    at javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.init(MediaPlayer.java:511)
    at javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.<init>(MediaPlayer.java:414)
    at sample.Main.start(Main.java:33)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$8(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$7(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$5(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$6(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$5(GtkApplication.java:139)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player!
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager.getPlayer(NativeMediaManager.java:274)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaManager.getPlayer(MediaManager.java:118)
    at javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.init(MediaPlayer.java:467)
    ... 11 more
Exception running application sample.Main

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Estoy utilizando:

- java version: 1.8.0_252
- javafx.version: 8.0.161-ea
- linux mint 19

Comment: edita tu pregunta, no pongas comentarios

Answer (score 0):

Podrías revisar si tu archivo de FXMLLoader está correcto. Quiero suponer que tienes algo así:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(Main.class.getResource("/NombreDeTuClase.fxml"));
```

Normalmente nos da error por dar un enlace incorrecto. Podrías checarlo en tu código y agregar un "/".